# what is the concept of Object-Persistence?

Tags: c++, object, persistence

what does `Object persistence` mean in c++?
Can you explain it with an example or provide links to where i could find the answer? 
Thank you.

Comment: In what context? This question is completely unanswerable. In English, words can have many definitions, and phrases many more. Beyond that, Stack Overflow is not really a good place to ask for definitions to things that can be easily found with a Google search. If the topic is significant, there's a good bet there's a Wikipedia article on it. If you have read that article and *still* have specific questions, please edit your question to reflect those.

Comment: @Code Gray & Robit : Thanks for your tips.. But there is a question that I come from China, you know ? Google is prohibit for long time in our country..What a pity. What we can use is Baidu which is big Search engine. But we can't get more information from it like Google. So i put this question..Thanks again..

Comment: oh sorry dude. you could have mentioned it. So anything more than that required? does that link solve your prob? and when you post question pls mention the context in which the question was posted. See FAQ for it.

Comment: Last time (a month ago) I have been in China google was working just fine ...

Comment: that image is irrelevant to the question. if its to let others know that google isnt working, your word on that would be more than enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Most objects cease to exist when they go out of scope. This may be
>   when the function in which they were created terminates. It may be
>   when the container in which they reside is deleted. At any rate, they
>   can be expected to disappear when the program exits. Persistent
>   objects are those which survive between successive invocations of the
>   program. A classic example of such an object is a database record.

check out the following links:

[C++ object persistence library similar to eternity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4804653/1155650)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/litesql/

http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/doc/manual.xhtml

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODB_(C%2B%2B)

http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184408893

http://tools.devshed.com/c/a/Web-Development/C-Programming-Persistence/

C++ doesn't support persistence directly (there are proposals for adding persistence and reflection to C++ in the future). Persistence support is not as trivial as it may seem at first. The size and memory layout of the same object may vary from one platform to another. Different byte ordering, or endian-ness, complicate matters even further. To make an object persistent, we have to reserve its state in a non-volatile storage device. ie: Write a persistent object to retain its state outside the scope of the program in which it was created.

Comment: Making C++ Objects Persistent: the Hidden Pointers a pdf is available but i cant find its link. if that is something which you think might be usefull i will post.

Comment: @Rohit presumably this is the PDF you mentioned: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.40.8479

Comment: I had read it, but It is not good to understood, can you help me to explain it by general word? it think it just a pointer and by new this key word.. right?

Comment: You read through the other references and got the basics of object persistence?

Comment: i had read the link you pasted about c++... But i can't understand well..In my mind, the persistence of object can be created by "new"

Comment: in what context are you requiring an answer? what are you trying to do with Object persistance? Maybe improve the question by adding some more detail into it

Comment: The question came from : when i read some passage about MFC, it said CObject support for persistence of a object.. but i don't what does it means

Comment: Unless written to some external file c++ objects do not support persistance. maybe you can find the article and post it as an edit to you question .

Comment: i understood it now, after try every way..Thank you very much. ^_^

Comment: Always Welcome!! Thats what so is for